# Unable to remove file with size greater than 2GB

Tags: shell, unix, sh, csh

I am trying to remove a file form unix shell scripting (`csh`) and the file size is greater than `2GB`due to which the command `rm test.csv` is giving the following error and also not removing the file.

`rm: test.csv: Value too large for defined data type`

File:
`-rw-r--r--   1 abcd  efgh   2227016509 Mar  6 03:19 test.csv`

command used: `rm test.csv`

Can you please help.

Comment: have you try with `/usr/bin/rm filename` or with `rm -f filename`?

Comment: Looks like [[EOVERFLOW](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) error

Comment: from documentation `  EOVERFLOW
              pathname refers to a regular file that is too large to be
              opened.  The usual scenario here is that an application
              compiled on a 32-bit platform without -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
              tried to open a file whose size exceeds (1<<31)-1 bytes; see
              also O_LARGEFILE above.  This is the error specified by
              POSIX.1; in kernels before 2.6.24, Linux gave the error EFBIG
              for this case.`

Comment: Can you please tell me how to rectify the above error?

Comment: The question isn't on-topic here at all, as it isn't about writing software. [unix.se] on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) are appropriate for questions about general UNIX usage. Beyond that, we'd want to know the operating system you're running (including the platform architecture; is this a 32-bit machine?) and the filesystem the file in question is on (which is to say... fat32? ntfs? Some as-yet-unspecified FUSE driver? It's unlikely that this is a modern, native Linux filesystem -- or, rather, if it is, we'd want to check for corruption or a platform-specific bug).

Answer (score 0):

try truncating the file first, eg :

```
truncate --size 0 test.csv
```

and then

```
rm -f test.csv
```